# Reference memory in service for 2 controllers to communicate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular, I am using a service for 2 controllers to communication and share the search box input variable.

I am referencing memory with `kickSearch.box`...`obj.property`. But for some reason, when `kickSearch.box` updates `$scope.searchBox` doesn't reflect the change:

```
angular.module('ucp.kick').controller('kickSearch', function($scope, $location, kickSearch) {
  initialize = function() {
    var terms;
    $scope.searchBox = kickSearch.box;
    terms = $location.search().device || $location.search().dc || [];
    kickSearch.box = _.isArray(terms) ? terms.join(" ") : terms;
    if ($scope.searchBox.length) {
      return $scope.submitSearch();
    }
  };
  initialize();
```

---

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter device #" ng-model="searchBox" >
```

Comment: in your case when you assing `kickSearch.box = _.isArray(terms)...` in `$scope.searchBox` saved old reference

Answer (score 1):

This is because `$scope.searchBox` does not carry a reference to `kickSearch.box`, but just its value when you request it.

There are a few ways to update your controller when your service updates. One way, is to use something akin to `$rootScope.$broadcast` or `$rootScope.$emit` to notify the controller that the service has been updated. Then, the controller can request the updated value from the service directly.